# point cloud librarby on visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, point-cloud-library

I have a problem during instalation of PCL for Visual Studio 2012. Can anyone describe me exactly, what should I do (step by step) because all tutorials that I have watched they don't contains all informations about configuration of this library.

I tried to install PCL 1.7.2 AllInOne and use Cmake 3.2, but it didn't work. Cmake gives information that some files is missing. And during instalation of PCL does not appear file: CmakeList, required by Cmake so I used file provided on Github: https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl.git

Answer (score 0):

I use PCL 1.7.2 and VS2012 in win8.1.
It's difficult to compile PCL from scratch.
This is my answer:[point cloud library on visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514762/point-cloud-library-on-visual-studio/29874373#29874373)