# How to integrate Point Cloud Library With Unity Google tango project?

Tags: point-cloud-library, google-project-tango, point-clouds

I am currently working with Google Tango  in Unity and i want to integrate Point Cloud Library(PCL) in order to process the point cloud data and segment the planes.I couldn't find any online references on this, so any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This basically explains how to integrate PCL with Unity, but once you have that, it should be possible to use with Google Tango as well.

1. depending on your version of VisualStudio, download and install [All-in-one Installer](http://unanancyowen.com/en/pcl18/) (be aware of 32 and 64-bit versions)
2. set environment variables
3. [create new project](http://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/10/11/how-to-write-native-plugins-for-unity/)
4. [include everything](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20837645/6247331) needed for **release** mode (it is important to set everything for release because unity won't work with debug .dll)
5. I had error that forced me to add also this: -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS in project properties
6. build project
7. copy generated .dll file to folder Assets/Plugins (if it doesn't exist create one)
8. call it from Unity (example code is under no 3.)
9. that's it!

PS: if after all these steps you start getting errors that .dll cannot be found although it exists in Plugins folder, try to restart your PC. It took me few hours of mostly useless googling to read some comment on SO suggesting that.